# Mocha --recursive flag throws an error

Tags: mocha.js

I am trying to set up Mocha to run in subfolders, so that my test directory can have some structure.

The --recursive flag should do this, but instead throws me an error.

This works (but doesn't go into subfolders):

```
mocha --timeout 10000 ./test
```

This throws an error:

```
mocha --recursive --timeout 10000 ./test
```

The error:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '../app'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb error-I did not change the path to app.js in my test files when I moved them to the subfolder (from `const app = require('../app'` 
to 
`const app = require('../../app');`);